# Custom SerializationBinder not called when deserializing

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have pretty simple code but can't get it working:

```
var binder = new TypeNameSerializationBinder("MyNamespace.{0}, MyAssembly");

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    Binder = binder
};

string json = ...
JsonSerializer js = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
// binder not called
var obj1 = js.Deserialize(new StringReader(json), bindingContext.ModelType);
// binder not called either
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, bindingContext.ModelType, settings);
// not called even when serializing
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, bindingContext.ModelType, settings);
```

**TypeNameSerializationBinder** is a simple binder I copied from [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/11/19/json-net-4-0-release-4-bug-fixes).
None of binder's method is called. $type attribute is ignored. All items get deserialized as parent class instances. The type I am trying to decerialize is `Dictionary<String, MyParentClass>`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your problem. Do add your class declaration and a sample of your JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

In JSON string the "$type" property should be first property of the object. This seems to be an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by _In JSON string the "$type" property should be first property of the object._